# VBScript not working? Page setup wrong

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, printing, vbscript

I have an Excel report program. When it prints, I want the date to be on the left.

I used this code

```
.LeftHeader = "Printed on &D &T"
```

However, I need to put a comment above in the "head" comment.

```
head = "In these quotes should be the date"
```

What should be in the quotes to print the date?

Answer (score 0):

The following gives date as formatted string . You can modify it to suit your requirements

```
head = Format(Date(), "yyyy/mm/dd")
```